# Function format representation form recognicion

Tags: python-2.7

Is it possible to get info about the representation of a number being passed to a function?
For example if I pass 0x14 (hex) or 0b10100 (binary), Python at some point must be aware (I guess) that I passed a number with that representation before it gets saved into an internal data format.

Can I access this information in order to handle the number as hex, binary, decimal (etc) when I want to print it inside the function (where this information is not directly available).

Comment: That's not *"formatting"*, they're just alternate literal forms for integers - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals. There's no information about which form you used. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I agree they _are_ alternate forms, but each one of them gets recognised and transformed to a single internal representation. Before that happens there must have been some piece of code that says "hey! this is a hex format!" , I was wondering if I could get advantage of that.

Comment: Get advantage *to what end*, though? The token the parser receives will be different, but the result is just an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what jonrsharpe noted in the comments, the literals `0x14` and `0b10100` in Python are both evaluated into plain old Python integer objects (i.e., `PyLongObject`). Once this parsing occurs (at compile time), the origin "format" used to represent the value in text is completely forgotten. If you want a function to behave different for "hex" numbers versus "binary" numbers, you'll have to either represent these values as strings instead of numbers, or pass an additional argument indicating the desired representation.